# How can I reload all of data in tableview when I click cancel on search bar?(IOS/Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I added `UISearchbar` and when I click the cancel button, I want to reload all the data on the tableview. But it shows the cell filtered by search bar. Instead of showing only search result, How can I reload all the data again?

```
@IBOutlet weak var mySearchBar: UISearchBar!    
@IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!


var foods = [Food]()
var foodsSearching = [Food]()

// search in progress or not
var isSearching : Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Use the edit button item provided by the table view controller.
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem()

    if let savedFoods = loadFoods() {
        foods += savedFoods
    } else {

    }

    // set table view delegate
     self.myTableView.dataSource = self
    self.myTableView.delegate = self

    // set search bar delegate
    self.mySearchBar.delegate = self
}
```

....

```
// hide keyboard when cancel button clicked
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.mySearchBar.text = ""
    self.mySearchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    self.myTableView.dataSource = self
    self.myTableView.delegate = self


    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    //need to reload all of data..not only the cells filtered by search bar
    self.myTableView.reloadData()


}
```

Comment: can you show some additioonal code

Comment: see this http://shrikar.com/swift-ios-tutorial-uisearchbar-and-uisearchbardelegate/

Comment: Try to add the code of `tableviewdelegate` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `isSearching` to `false` on `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` before reloading the table view. On tableview delegates, check if `isSearching` is true then use `foods` array, otherwise use `foodsSearching` array.